# Can anyone explain me how to overcome TLE error in Java. I'm getting Time Limit Exceeded in 3 inputs which are taking 100000 test cases as input

Tags: java, string

Can anyone explain me how to overcome TLE error in Java.

So, I implemented a seating arrangement code in which first line of input take test cases and second line of input takes seat number. In output I've to display the facing seat number of my input and seat type WS, AS or MS.

For example:

```
2 // test cases
18 // seat number
40 // seat number
19 WS // Output
45 AS // Output
```

Here is my code which I implemented :

```
import java.io.*;

class Solution9
{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
    {
        int tc;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    tc=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int sno,q,r;
    String type,s="";
    for(int i=0;i<tc;i++)
    {
        sno=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        sno--;
        q=sno/12;
        r=sno%12;
        int csno;
        csno=11-r;
        csno+=q*12;
        r%=6;
        if(r==0 || r==5)
            type="WS";
        else if(r==1 || r==4)
            type="MS";
        else
            type="AS";
        s=s+ (csno+1) + " " + type + "\n" ;
    }
        System.out.println(s);    
    }
}
```

Comment: May I recommend to post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? You'd probably benefit from some hints on code style over there, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff good idea but only after the code is error-free, otherwise it would be off-topc on Code Review.

Comment: @Heslacher I didn't check it, but I assumed the code is correct, only too slow.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff oh well, I just overlooked the TLE. Sure having only a TLE will be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your program under control of a profiler tool, you'll most probably notice a huge amount of time spent in `StringBuilder` activities around your line

```
s=s+ (csno+1) + " " + type + "\n" ;
```

Repeatedly adding something to a `String` is inefficient, as every time it does the following:

- Copy the existing string `s` into a `StringBuilder` (takes time proportional to the ever-increasing length of the string),
- append the other components to the `StringBuilder`,
- create a new `String` from the `StringBuilder` contents (again takes time proportional to the ever-increasing length of the contents).

As you aren't really interested in the intermediate Strings, but only in the final result, replace

```
String s="";
```

with

```
StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
```

and

```
s=s+ (csno+1) + " " + type + "\n" ;
```

with

```
s.append(csno+1).append(" ").append(type).append("\n");
```

This should give a substantial performance boost.

As `String`s in Java are immutable, "changing" anything about a `String` means to somehow create a new `String` (and probably forget about the old one). So it's better to use a `StringBuilder` until you're ready for the final result, because `StringBuilder`s allow changing their contents without repeatedly creating new ones.

Comment: As of, I think, Java 11 (but maybe 8) this is no longer true.  They made a special case for repeated String adds in a single statement and no longer create a new String for each plus.  But before this change, you were very correct -- it was a performance disaster.

Comment: @Zag repeated String adds *within a single statement* have always given one StringBuilder (or StringBuffer). I haven't checked whether Java11 or similar introduced a runtime optimization to keep the StringBuilder instead of the String from iteration to iteration. Not impossible, but quite some high-level reasoning necessary.

Comment: You're completely correct.  I didn't realize that he was collecting the entire string and not outputting line by line.  So, yeah, it is making a new string for each line of input, and they're getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: @Zag+ beginning j9 (including 11) it uses a partly-native InvokeDynamic instead of StringBuilder. But still only _within one statement_, so it's still repeatedly copying an increasingly large amount of data.  Although in j9 up, String values that contain only Latin-1 (aka 8859-1 or block 0) characters are stored as single bytes instead of 2 bytes, so it's only half as increasingly large. To optimize you do still need to use StringBuilder because you can't get at the InvokeDynamic directly.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ralf Kleberhoff, it solved TLE error. It is working fine by using StringBuilder I wasn't knowing this. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your problem is the performance of your code.  It could be improved but not by an order of magnitude or anything.  I suspect the problem is that your input file is improperly formed, where it is saying that it has more lines than it actually has.  Since your first line says how many lines to expect and you are streaming from System.in rather than using File io, it will wait until it sees the lines it expects.  System.in will not produce an EOF exception the way a FileReader would, it'll just wait.

Edit:  Oh!  Wait!  I take it back.  You're collecting the entire output into a single string and not outputting any of it until your entire input is processed.  Think how huge that string is getting!  You're probably running out of memory.

Also, Ralf Kleberhoff is completely correct that you're making a new string (copying the whole string in order to add to it) for every row.  Consider how much is being copied as you're doing the last couple hundred of your 100,000 rows.

You really have to be outputting as you go along.  This makes it awkward to test manually from standard in, but you should get over that.  Test from test files.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Yes, error was in that one line only.